# Service is destroyed again and again

Tags: android, android-service

I created an android class extending service and implemented its methods but service is destroyed after some time and again and again its oncreate method is called.

```
public class X extends Service {
String doTask;
String username;
ParseObject obj;

Handler h3;
ParseFile file;
Runnable r3 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            try {
             YService yS = new YService();
                yS.execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        h3.postDelayed(r3, 60000);

    }

};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        try {
            h3 = new Handler();
            h3.postDelayed(r3, 60000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private class yService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TODOTasks");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getUsername());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            String task;

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() == 0) {
                    }
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        po = objects.get(0);

                        NewServiceCaller(obj.getString("task"));

                    }

                } else {

                }

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

}
```

I tried to debug this and I think Control is reaching here and from here there is some mistake.

```
    private void commandexecuter(String commandtoexecute) {
    if (commandtoexecute.equals("do some task")) {
        try{
        startService(new Intent(X.this,CalledService.class));
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> service is destroyed after some time and again and again its oncreate method is called

That is perfectly normal behavior for a service. [An Android SDK app process does not live forever](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). It will be terminated to free up memory for other processes. By returning `START_STICKY`, you are asking Android to restart your process some time later, after that occurs.

Comment: Ohh I thought there was some mistake in my code.Is my code correct?

Comment: And I am doing some upload task in my service class will it not create problem if the service is destroyed in the middle of the upload task,?

Comment: @AryanArya: "Is my code correct?" -- I have no idea, as I have no idea what you are trying to do. I can tell you that using `postDelayed()` and `AsyncTask` in a `Service` are both code smells IMHO, and doing something once a minute is likely to be user-hostile. "will it not create problem if the service is destroyed in the middle of the upload task" -- your upload will be interrupted if Android terminates your process.

Comment: @CommansWare I am pushing some tasks for the device to do on the Parse Cloud and after every minute I am checking if any new task is there for the app to do.Is there any better thing which I can use in place of AsyncTask and postDelayed?

Comment: @AryanArya: That would be a question for the support engineers at Parse. I have not used Parse and therefore I do not know if they offer a push messaging option that you could use instead of polling every minute. Polling every minute is very hard on the device battery, and keeping a service running constantly is a waste of RAM. If you must poll, allow the user to configure the polling period, then use `AlarmManager`, `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and an `IntentService` to do the periodic work.

Comment: And I set 1 minute for my convenience,so that I can check if the service is working properly  or not.Otherwise it will be checked after every 10 minutes :)